# Distribution F in a renewal process

Tags: stochastic-processes

Referring  to the Ross textbook stochastic processes, define the inter arrival times $x_i$ follow a distribution $F$. What is F representing here the PDF or CDF? What would $\overline{F}$ represent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$F$ = CDF. $\bar F=1-F$. $ $ $ $

Comment: I was unsure if he was talking about the mean or the CCDF. Thanks for the clarification.